# How to write a bash script to generate a file named inputFile with comma separated values with index and a random number

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

Could someone help on how to write an bash script to generate a file named `inputFile` whose content looks like:

```
0, 334

1, 933

2, 34123

3, 123
```

These are comma separated values with index and a random number.

-> Running the script without any arguments, should generate the file `inputFile` with 10 such entries in current directory.

-> You should be able to extend this script to generate any number of entries, for example 100000 entries.

I tried below script but its not as expected, could someone help me to fix this?

```bash
RANDOM=$$
num=0

while [[ ${num} -le $1 ]]
do
    echo $num $RANDOM
    (( num = num +1 ))
done
```

Comment: If you do really want **random numbers** just remove the line `RANDOM=$$`. From `man bash`: *RANDOM: Each time this parameter is referenced, it expands to a random integer between 0 and 32767*

Comment: @EdgarMagallon  The assignment to RANDOM is outside the loop, so `$$` (the shell's pid) is used as the seed of the sequence. At least it varies on each run. Bash Ref Manual does not say how RANDOM is initialised, but I found a post that claimed: `gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);`  `sbrand (tv.tv_sec ^ tv.tv_usec ^ getpid ());`

Comment: @Paul_Pedant oh, that's right! I thought it was setting a new seed every loop but yes, it's outside the loop. And thanks for the last info, that's useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off.

I'd probably set a variable, say `count` to the first command line parameter (`$1`), and then check if it's empty, which case you could set it to 10.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
RANDOM=$$
count="$1"
[[ -z "$count" ]] && count=10

num=0
while [[ ${num} -le ${count} ]]
do
    echo $num, $RANDOM
    (( num = num +1 ))
done > inputFile
```

Technically that will give you 11 random numbers, not 10, since it starts with 0 and ends with 10, To change that, either start `num` at 1 (to get 1–10), or use `-lt` rather then `-le` (to get 0–9).

Be sure to put a comma in the echo command if you want a comma between the numbers in the output.

You can use any other number than 10 to get more random numbers. `bash script.sh 10000`.

BTW `inputFile` is a weird name for an output file.